# is Invitation mandatory for Canada or Russian Federation?

Tags: canada, standard-visitor-visas, russia, nigerian-citizens, invitation-letters

How compulsory is it to have a visit invitation when applying to a nation like Canada or Russia ? I have wanted to visit either of the two, but I do not have an understanding of how the processes are and I also hear its mandatory to have a letter of invitation prior to visit. In the event I do not have anyone there and all i have for accomodation is booking of a Hotel (Hotel reservation), can this work at this point. Not a frequent traveller to Eastern Europe / EurAsia and the Americas, hence i just wanted to be sure of things beforehand.

Plus I am a Nigerian Citizen, and i need Clear and concise answers.

Comment: An invitation isn’t necessary for Canada. You can use this tool https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/come-canada-tool.html to find out if you’re eligible to apply and to get a personalized document checklist that provides you with a list of documents you need to submit, according to your specific situation.

Comment: I see, and pls any idea of the maximum validity of the visa. I tend to see 10 years there, does it mean the visa should be valid for 10 years for Nigeria citizens , where i can visit for every 6 months. I obviously need good clarification here

Comment: Please only ask one question per question and do not add aditional questions in the comments. Canada and Russia have different rules.

Comment: @Fred All the information you need is available on the Government of Canada website I linked to. Whether you qualify for a visit visa depends on your circumstances (finances, ties to home, reason for wanting to visit etc). Immigration officials tend to view Nigeria as a high immigration risk country, so any application needs to be watertight.

Answer (score 2):

For Russia: an invitation is mandatory, but it is given to you by the hotel or the travel agency you book the travel, if you are staying for tourism. It is very easy to get, and as far I know, it is not really checked after you get it.

[In my case, I had to change completely the plans, and cancel a tour, but I did a much shorter tourist travel in Russia privately organized. Russian travel agency and in any case Russia immigration were ok].

Note: if you plan to stay by a private accommodation (e.g. a friend), this is more complex, and your friend needs some official documents. Embassies website have the links.

On the other hand, you are a Nigerian. Many Nigerians are not following the rules, so embassies and immigration officers are much more strict.